# Using SQL_VARIANT in OData query ($select, $orderby)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, odata, .net-7.0

Is there any way to use a `SQL_VARIANT` column in OData queries? we are talking about `$select`, `$orderby`, `$filter` etc.

I'm trying to create a table on the web side that will display data from several other tables on the database side. One of them is a table containing a `SQL_VARIANT` column. To do this, I created an indexed view containing columns from several tables, so that I could connect OData to retrieve data, filter, sort, etc. (If I understand correctly, for pagination etc. to work OData must be connected to one table?) I created the view, `$count` and `$select *` worked as well, but problems occurred when using a `SQL_VARIANT` column (`object` on the c# side) in `$select` or `$Orderby` ends up with errors like:

`The query specified in the URI is not valid. The $orderby expression must evaluate to a single value of primitive type.`

`The query specified in the URI is not valid. The given model does not contain the type 'System.Object'.`

Is there any way around this? I wanted to replace `sql_variant` with `float` in the view, but I can't use `CAST` in an indexed view.

Comment: Don't use that type. OData isn't a database API. It returns objects with specific schemas and entity types. SQL_Variant is *not* the equivalent of `object` in C# either. Using `object` is discouraged ever since generics were introduced. In JSON, OData's serialization format, it's not needed at all, because a JSON attribute can be anything

Comment: Unfortunately this type has been used for a very long time in the old database and they can't get rid of it :( `Using object is discouraged ever since generics were introduced` can you explain? using `object` in c#?

Comment: Any other ideas? maybe I can convert SQL_VARIANT to a string on the OData side?